# How to handle Amazon S3 updates for transactional data

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a transactional table that I load from SQL server to Amazon S3  S3 using AWS DMS. For handling updates I move the old files to archive and then process only the incremental records everytime.

This is fine when I have only insert operation in my database. But problem comes when we need to accomodate the updates. Right now for doing any updates we read the entire S3 file and make changes to the records which are updated as a part of incremental load. Then as the data keeps on increasing the process of reading the entire file in S3 bucket and updating it would take more time and in future the job might not be able to end in time (Considering that job needs to end in 1 hour).

This can be handled using Databricks where we can use Delta Table to update the records and finally overwrite the existing file. But Databricks is bit expensive.

How do we handle the same using AWS Glue?